# Guaranteed termination of external process in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have launched a GHCi external process like this

```
(Just hin, Just hout, _, pid) <- createProcess (proc "ghci" ["-fdefer-type-errors"])
    { std_in = CreatePipe, std_out = CreatePipe, std_err = UseHandle stdout }
```

which I control by writing to `hin` and reading from `hout`. This is used to load an Haskell file into the external GHCi process, call one of its functions, and read its results, all this problematic.

My problem is that sometimes there is some function that runs indefinetely when called, like `f n = sum [n..]`, and when this happens I want to terminate the external GHCi process.

To do so, I have tried calling the function `terminateProcess pid` but it does not kill the process reliably; in general, the external process stops working, yet it still appears when I type `$ ps` at the console. For example, this is an example of top's output when the ghc external process is eating the processor:

```
PID    COMMAND      %CPU  TIME      ...
38312  top          3.3   00:00.89 
38309  ghc          99.9  00:21.46 
38306  ghc          0.0   00:00.82
```

and when I try to end it using `terminateProcess pid` it usually brings down the process to 0% CPU, but is still there:

```
PID    COMMAND      %CPU     TIME      ...
38312  top          3.3   00:00.89
38309  ghc          0.0   00:21.46 
38306  ghc          0.0   00:00.82
```

Sometimes, I need to call `terminateProcess pid` several times to make the external ghc stop, yet it is sill always there. Even then, after it stopped, when I try `waitForProcess pid` this one blocks.

Is there a reliable way in Haskell to completely terminate an external process for sure? Like the Unix `kill -9 38309` always does?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Posix systems `terminateProcess` just sends a SIGTERM signal.

Here is some code which demonstrates how to send a SIGKILL signal to a Posix process which was created using `System.Process`:

```
import System.Process
import System.Process.Internals
import System.Posix.Signals

main = do
  (_, _, _, ph) <- createProcess (shell "asd")
  -- ...
  withProcessHandle ph $ \ph_ ->
    case ph_ of
      OpenHandle pid -> signalProcess sigKILL pid
      ClosedHandle _ -> return ()                   -- shouldn't happen
```

Comment: That code works, but at the end we need to do `waitForProcess ph`, otherwise there will be process entries like `(ghc)` in the `$ ps` process list. Do you know why is `waitForProcess ph` needed to cleanup these `(ghc)` entries? What do they mean?

Comment: The operating system keeps track of the process until the parent does a `wait` call. Look up [zombie processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process)  for more details.

Comment: One more question: do I need to close the input and output handles before killing the process or this is done automatically by the OS?

Comment: You'll need to close your end of any pipes that were created when spawning the process - this is not done automatically.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: Apparently, this code creates a shell plus a process for `asd`, kills the shell and hopes that `asd` dies. That's not reliable—it relies on job control hence it breaks if the process is not connected to a terminal. Using `proc` rather than `shell` is more robust. We've run into this in the wild. Details in this issue: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3250#issuecomment-313340444